# Override ArrayList.equals in Android activity

Tags: android, arraylist, overriding, equals, contains

I have an arraylist of objects which contain multiple variables.

I generate new objects and want to conditionally check to see that an object with the same contents does not exist anyhwere in the arraylist.

Unfortunately both Arraylist.contains(object)  and Arraylist.equals(object) only check for references of the same object, instead of objects with the same components. I want it to act like a much simpler String.contains("x") does.

How do I override arraylist.equals/arraylist.contains to do what I want within my android activity?

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood the question, but you shouldn't have to override the equals on the ArrayList. The equals(Object o) and contains(Object o) methods for ArrayList both call the equals methods on each of the objects in them. So if you are only getting shallow comparisons it's because the object you are putting in the ArrayList hasn't overridden the equals method to properly compare its own components.

Comment: @combinatorics , oh! duh this was obvious, thank you for pointing this out

Comment: No probs. I will post my original comment as an answer so we can close this question out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create your own class that inherits from ArrayList and define your own definition for both.

```
public class myArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    @Override
    public Boolean equals(object o) {
        //Your implementation
    }
    @Override
    public Boolean contains(object o) {
        //Your implementation
    }
}
```

Then replace your ArrayList types with MyArrayList types.

Or you could just make a method somewhere that accepts 2 ArrayLists and tells you if they are equal, or if one contains the other.

```
public static Boolean areArrayListsEqual(ArrayList a, ArrayList b) {
     //Check if they are equal
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The equals(Object o) and contains(Object o) methods for ArrayList both call the equals methods on each of the objects in them. So if you are only getting shallow comparisons it's because the object you are putting in the ArrayList hasn't overridden the equals method to properly compare its own components.